# Folders are not creating after running this command - manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension -f edgeextension -m <EXTENSION LOCATION>\manifest.json

Tags: packaging, microsoft-edge-extension, manifoldjs

This is command for packaging edge extension -
manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension -f edgeextension -m \manifest.json.
 - I gave here the path of my extension manifest.json file.

After manifoldjs finished running following folders should create -

My Extension
edgeextension
generationInfo.json
manifest
AppXManifest.xml
Assets
Logo.png
Extension
manifest.json
popup.html
...
But in my case, folders are not creating and I am unable to package my extension.

Comment: Does using the Node V8 help you to fix the issue? If yes, I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to check the description and it looks like you are developing an extension for the MS Edge legacy browser.

I try to refer to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/using-manifoldjs-to-package-extensions#packaging-with-manifoldjs) and try to create and package sample extension.

I got the output below:

[image]

When I try to check the folder then I noticed that folder is empty. So based on my test result I am able to produce the issue.

I try to check the old threads and found that it is a [known issue](https://github.com/pwa-builder/manifoldjs-edgeextension/issues/19).

I found that issue occurs if the users are using the Node V10. In that thread, users had mentioned that it will work fine with the **Node V8**. I suggest trying to make a test with the Node V8 may help you to fix the issue.

Further, I suggest you can try to provide feedback about this issue on their [Github](https://github.com/pwa-builder/manifoldjs-edgeextension) page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It’s really helpful.